# Play framework 2.5 how to set mode?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.5

The application object has the `isDev()`, `isTest()` and `isProd()` methods.

But I can't find out where to set this in the `.conf` file.

Using the search feature on the website for "mode", "dev", "test" or "prod" gives nothing related to this. This doesn't appear to be documented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Production mode use: `activator stage` or  `activator dist`
- Dev mode use `activator run`

To test a production mode, run (not to be used in production):

```
cd project-dir
activator
testProd
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for that. I saw that before on this page: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/SBTCookbook, but didn't find anything else.